# Can't resolve 'numeral' in Angular app model

Tags: angular, typescript, numeral.js

I `npm i numerals`, then `npm i @types/numeral`.

I am trying to use numeral inside my price.model.ts file.  So, I imported it: `import * as numeral from 'numeral';`

But, I'm getting this error: `./src/app/shared/models/price.model.ts:1:0-35 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'numeral' in '\src\app\shared\models'`

Right now, I'm just using it to parse the number|string that is coming in.  I plan to use it for arithmetic later.

```
private parseValue(value: number | string): number {
  let numeralValue = numeral(value).value();
  if (numeralValue === null) throw new Error(`${value} is Nan.`);

  return numeralValue.valueOf();
}
```

There's no squigglies prior to compile.  I only get the error on ng serve.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please share code for the module file as well as the model file in order to understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`numerals` and `@types/numeral` are different packages.

If you want to use `numerals`, just import what you need:

`import { Language, NumeralForm, convertNumberToNumeralForm } from 'numerals';`

Comment: I was following this (http://www.alternatestack.com/development/app-development/angular2-using-3rd-party-libraries/) as a guide.  I tried just @types/numeral and still get the error.

Comment: don't use @types/numeral, just read the NPM packge README: https://www.npmjs.com/package/numerals

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I installed "numerals" instead of "numeral".  I needed both `npm i numeral` and `npm i @types/numeral` for it to work.